# Is it possible to make certain lines within a Dockerfile architecture dependent?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile and I need to include different lines depending on whether I'm running it on my development environment or a raspberry pi.

Can I add in some sort of architecture dependent IF statement around the only lines that vary?

```
# x64 version (shortened)
FROM node:10

COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential g++

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main' > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev
```

The apt source between architectures varies.

```
# ARM / Raspbian version.  (shortened)
FROM node:10

COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential g++

RUN wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.public.key -O - | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main' > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev
```

Comment: Interesting question in as much as as one of the generally touted advantage of docker being the production of immutable images that are portable. I don't think such a feature exists as conditional statements in the build process. I think the `node:10` tag is building from this: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/8efaa064853a2f866481f162eb4e424c5ee8ac9e/10/jessie/Dockerfile with supported architectures listed here: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/ Perhaps you can build the image on one architecture and one you have the image build run it on various supported ones by pulling the image?

Comment: Out of interest, when you don't try to define the apt-source at all yourself in either circumstance, what happens?

Comment: @DavidGoate, in both circumstances, ruby2.3 can't be found to install.

Answer (score 2):

In docker file you can use `ARG` do define parameter for your build process like:

```
FROM node:10
ARG platform=x64
```

[documentation for it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

you can call it like this to change default value

```
docker build --build-arg platform=arm
```

and inside your docker file it behaves like any other variable so you can if on it:

```
RUN if [ "$platform" = "arm" ]; then ... else ... fi
```